# Can I add a mask to an svg-element without using an id?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to assign a svg-mask to a svg-image. I can make this work using an id on the mask like this:

```html
<svg id="svg1" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <defs>
       <mask id="mask">
         <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="white"></circle>
       </mask>   
     </defs>
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#mask)"></rect>
</svg>
```

However I want to load this svg multiple times, with a different id in the svg-tag. Therefore I will generate duplicates of the '#mask'-id. Using multiple id's is invalid code. So I want to use a class to refer to the appropriate mask. That means I cannot use the `mask=url()`-technique.

```html
<svg id="svg2" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
     <defs>
       <mask class="mask">
         <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" fill="white"></circle>
       </mask>   
     </defs>
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(can't use this)"></rect>
</svg>
```

Is there a way I can apply a mask to the rect element if the mask has a class instead of id? Maybe using javaScript or some other way I didn't think of.

***The full story/context:***
I am actually making an svg image slider-module for Joomla with php. This php generates a module containing javascript, css and an svg. I use the javascript to animate the mask. 
I do actually have it working with unique id's. I was just wondering if there is a way to assign a mask to an element without referring to id's. I may want to do this because my code is getting a bit more confusing to read, because I have to use some php in my javascript/svg and css for each unique id.

Comment: Is the mask always the same? If so, load it once separately. Or generate and use a different id for each (derived from the svg element is, for instance)

Comment: @jcaron No the masks are not always the same. They can be the same sometimes, but not always. At the moment I am using the different id-approach. But I think I might prefer to refer to it changing only one id in the entire svg.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You can only reference masks via an `id`. You cannot reference SVG masks any other way.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the case. I'll wait a week or so accepting the answer in case someone suddenly shows up with a miracle solution :p. Feel free to remind me if I forget xD.

Comment: There won't be a miracle solution. You can verify this yourself by reading the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html).  :)

Answer (score 6):

According to your description I understand you have a identical grafical entity you want to mask with different forms, multiple times. Write that down DRY:

```html
<!-- start with an invisible svg that only contains mask definitions -->
<svg width="0" height="0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <!-- first, you have a circular mask -->
       <mask id="circle-mask">
         <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" fill="white" />
       </mask>   
        <!-- then, you have a different mask, lets say a diamond -->
       <mask id="diamond-mask">
         <polygon points="100,20 180,100 100,180 20,100" fill="white" />
       </mask>   
     </defs>
</svg>

<!-- further into your document, you want to mask a rectangle -->
<svg id="svg1" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- reference the circle mask -->
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#circle-mask)" />
</svg>

<!-- with the circle again, as often as you want, nothing changes -->
<svg id="svg2" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- the mask is the same, so no difference to above -->
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#circle-mask)" />
</svg>

<!-- and now with the diamond; that one is different -->
<svg id="svg3" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <!-- if the mask changes, you need to change the reference -->
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" mask="url(#diamond-mask)" />
</svg>
```

You could also reference the masks in a stylesheet and give your referencing elements a class according to the mask shape:

```css
.masked.circular rect {
    mask: url(#circle-mask);
}
.masked.diamond rect {
    mask: url(#diamond-mask);
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
       <mask id="circle-mask">
         <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="80" fill="white" />
       </mask>   
       <mask id="diamond-mask">
         <polygon points="100,20 180,100 100,180 20,100" fill="white" />
       </mask>   
     </defs>
</svg>

<svg id="svg1" class="masked circular" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" class="masked circular" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
</svg>

<svg id="svg1" class="masked diamond" width="5cm" height="5cm" viewBox="0 0 200 200"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That wouldn't work for me. I suppose I should have provided more context in the question (I tried to keep the question as simple as possible). I added the situation to the question. Thx for trying to answer tough ;).